# Node.js promise .then() chaining with defined function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

How can I use `.then()` chaining to call a function that is declared in Node.js? The problem is after the call to `getFileType()` I want to call `getExif()` but this is throwing a syntax error:

```js
'use strict';

const FileType = require('file-type');
const exif = require('jpeg-exif');

const path = './alcatraz.jpg';

async function getFileType(filePath) {
    return await FileType.fromFile(filePath);
}

function getExif(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exif.parse(filePath, (error, result) => {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

getFileType(path).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
# ======> problem is here <======
.then(getExif(path) {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(3);
});
```

Syntax error is:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Comment: you are passing callback function as an argument while calling `then` function which is not that function which you want to execute, this will be treated as another function.. You should do something like this : `getFileType(path).then((result) => { console.log(result); return path; }).then(getExif).catch((error) => { console.error(error.message); process.exit(3); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return the call to `getExif(path)` inside the upper `.then`, so that the lower `.then` can consume it:

```
getFileType(path).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return getExif(path);
})
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(3);
});
```

The `result` variable in the lower `.then` will contain the result of calling `getExif`. If you want both the `getFileType` and `getExif` resolve values, since they don't look to depend on each other, use `Promise.all` instead:

```
Promise.all([
  getFileType(path),
  getExif(path),
])
  .then(([fileType, exif]) => {
    // work with results
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(3);
  });
```

Comment: Ah, that is kind of weird calling `getExif` from the `getFileType` callback. Is there no way to chain `.then()`?

Comment: That *is* how you chain `.then`s - at the last line of the upper `.then`, return the Promise and the lower `.then`'s argument will be that resolve value. Could also use `await`, which makes things cleaner when you have 2 or more `.then`s

Comment: Your `Promise.all()` example is perfect. Just for my knowledge, could you show an example of using `await` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do this to get result of getExif.

```
getFileType(path)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
  })
  .then(getExif(path)
    .then(resultOfGetExif => console.log(resultOfGetExif))
  )
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(3);
  });
```

or this just running getExif

```
getFileType(path)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  })
  .then((result) => {
    getExif(path)
    console.log(result);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message);
    process.exit(3);
  });
```

I hope these are helpful.

Comment: your first code is wrong, since `getExif` will be called immediately